# Turn-key docker-compose solution to start developing with Node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, web-applications, docker-compose

I am looking for a simple, no frills, docker-compose based solution so I can start playing with some common tools, without having to devote lots of time into learning to configure the infrastructure. It should pull from the official images of the included projects, to make things super standardized and easy to move forward.

Ideally, I can have local directories mounted, so I can just edit my code directly, and have it served up through the container. Even better is to have the database stored similarly, in case I wind up liking it and want to port it into a project.

---

Edit:
Since it seems nobody gets it. The reasons for wanting this are:

1. No local installation of tools to pollute my development environment.
2. No rebuilding of containers as I change my code, learn, and test out features.
3. Not using any exotic features or special configuration, so official containers from the distributions should be sufficient.
4. Clean roadmap to scaling up to a real project. Acts as a template going forward.
5. Not spending time on tasks that are not relevant to the final goal (configuring a platform that may never be used).

It seems clear to me that a significant portion of development should use containerized runtimes for building/testing, without installing things on the real host. That would avoid a lot of hassles and conflicts, and allows easy revisiting of old development environments.

---

This seems like an obvious thing that should be readily available, just like the standard images that many projects provide.

As I am just looking to evaluate things, I'm not that picky about tools. A development language/framework (Node.js), a database (MySQL), and web server capability (anything). If it's PostgreSQL, MongoDB, whatever. I just don't want to spend days wrestling with setting things up, before I actually get to start evaluating the platform.

I [tried asking this](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/11781/are-there-turn-key-development-webapp-containers-for-evaluation) over on DevOps a few days ago. All I got was one snarky and unhelpful comment, which has since been deleted.

I have tried following a bunch of different tutorials around the web and answers given here, but they all fail, and I really don't want to get sidetracked debugging them.

It seems like this would be a common template for starting many projects, regardless of complexity or expertise. So, I'm really surprised I can't find it. It also seems like a good way to lure in new users, which should incentivize project maintainers to have these.

Comment: this question is too broad IMO and you don't show an effort to solve it yourself.

Comment: You can just [download Node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), and most OS package managers have it prepackaged.  There's no particular reason to involve Docker just to start playing with the language.

Comment: I don't want to pollute my development system. That is the main reason to use a container.I also want to use the basic stuff, like a database, so again - container.

Comment: I already put in more effort solving it myself than makes sense. I spent way too much time going through numerous tutorials, but not one actually works without debugging. My time is valuable and could be spent on productive things, instead of wasted on solving infrastructure nonsense, for a platform I may not wind up using, that is routinely done by many people, The question isn't broad - I want a set of containers that act like a typical server setup. The language in isolation is of no interest.